# Fetching two URLs in root reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a reviews system (you can rate a meal 1-5 stars) and have two json files with data (stars.json, comments.json). I want the root component (Reviews) to be able to fetch both stars.json and comments.json. How would I do this? Right now I only know how to point to one file.

```
React.render(<Reviews url='stars.json' />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: can you post what reviews looks like? why cant you just pass them both in as props `<Reviews starsUrl='stars.json' commentsUrl='comments.json' />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a central file that composes both these elements. The key to React is small, composable components.

As in...

```
'use strict'
let ComposingComponent = React.createClass({
  let CompA = require('./comp-a');
  let CompB = require('./comp-b');

  render() {
    return( 
     <div>
      <CompA />
      <CompB />
    </div>
   );
  }
});
```